# Get date from datestring

Tags: date, code-documentation, calllog, verizon

I saw you do it for someone but I can't click anything and it doesn't make sense to me to do myself can someone tell me the date out of this dateString 1663099299947 and please explain so I can figure out the rest myself

None of the previous answers made sense to me

Answer (score 0):

1663099299947 is your date represented as the number of seconds since 1970. From Javascript you can use it like so.

```
new Date(1663099299947) //Date Wed Sep 14 2022 06:01:39
```

(For your reference [Mozilla Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#the_ecmascript_epoch_and_timestamps))